# Calling external class members from shared object

Tags: c++, c++11, pointer-to-member

After lot of reading [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/94579) and [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html), I still cannot get my code to work. Here is the problem:

I have two classes, Fifo:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
 #endif 

class Fifo
{
public:

   Fifo(int len);
   ~Fifo();

   void  AddTokens(void* buffer, unsigned len);

private:

   // some variables here

};

#ifdef __cplusplus
 }
 #endif
```

and another class Process_Wrapper:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
 #endif 


class Process_Wrapper
{
    public:
        Process_Wrapper(const std::string process_name);
        Fifo* GetOutputPortIDtoFifoMap(int portID);
        virtual ~Process_Wrapper();
    protected:
private:
    //some variables here
};

#ifdef __cplusplus
 }
 #endif
```

The member function `Process_Wrapper::GetOutputPortIDtoFifoMap` returns a pointer to an initialized object of class `Fifo`.

Now, I have a shared object (.so), which is compiled with headers for classes `Fifo` and `Process_Wrapper` included. That is, the .so file knows the interfaces to these classes.

I call this .so file from a member function of `Process_Wrapper` (`Process_Wrapper::function2`) and pass to .so a pointer - `this`. So, I assume that the shared object will know everything about the class `Process_Wrapper`.

In the .so file, I am trying to call the member function `Process_Wrapper::GetOutputPortIDtoFifoMap`, which obviously does not work. So, I tried:

```
Fifo* (Process_Wrapper::*GetFifoMapping)(int) = p1->wptr->GetOutputPortIDtoFifoMap;
```

where `p1->wptr` returns a pointer to `Process_Wrapper` object correctly.

I am lost here. I am quite new to this concept, and the examples do not directly answer the question. How do I go about doing it?

Also, since I am using C++0x/C++11, can anyone tell me (preferably) the solution using std::bind, or mem__fun_ref?

**Edit:** Okay, I think I can refine my question: I have a class `Myclass`, and an object `myobject`, which is an instance of this class. `Myclass` has a member function, taking some arguments, and returning a pointer of type `PTRTYPE`. How do I extract the member function of `Myclass` to be passed to another function, such that it can be used as a normal pointer-to-function. Or, specifically: How do I extracting the function pointer from a bound pointer to member function?

Comment: You just want to pass a method-pointer, that's it?

Comment: Where did you learn C++?

Comment: "How do I extracting the function pointer from a bound pointer to member function?" You can't.

Comment: Well, to answer @StackedCrooked: I am learning C++. So, if you think what I asked is awful, it would be nice if you explained me so. Meanwhile, I found this(http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Bound-member-functions.html). Heck, I still dont get it.

Comment: Oh, with a compiler-specific extension that might be doable. But in a portable way it's not.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, I was passing "this" pointer to the .so object. However, at run-time, I was getting the error about a symbol not found. This symbol was 'U' or unmapped in the .so file but was defined in the main exe ('T') which would load this .so. All I had to do was add '-rdynamic' to the linker option that produced the main exe.

Clearly, I did not see the problem was that simple, and my (incorrect) hypothesis was that the problem was related to correctly using the pointer to member function of an initialized object.

I understand that the problem description I posted may not have been clear, so apologies for that.

Thanks everyone.